# Как при посыле сигнала вывести процент выполнения цикла?

Tags: linux, c, обработка-сигналов

```
int a = 1;
for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++){
     a = a * i;
}
```

Comment: А почему бы не делить на верхнюю границу цикла, и потом умножать на 100?
Ну, например, пройдено 500 итераций из цикла. Таким образом, (500/1000)*100 = 50 (%).

Comment: да, но нужно послать SIGINT, а потом вывести процент. Мне непонятно как это сделать

Comment: @user_1234567890 очевидно, что это потребует float арифметики, когда можно обойтись без её использования.

Comment: ТС: а вы хотя бы начали с примеров из документации?

Comment: тут вопрос больше в замыкании. как указатель на i передать в обработчик сигнала?

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int flag;

void mysig(int signum) {
  flag = 1;
}

int main() {

  signal(SIGUSR1, mysig);

  int a = 1;
  for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    a = a * i;
    if (flag == 1) {
      flag = 0;
      printf("%d\n", i / 10);
    }
  }
  return (0);
}
```

Comment: В данном случае конечно не страшно, а так где гарантия, что между условием и присваиванием не придёт ещё раз сигнал?

Comment: @0andriy поменять присваивание на инкремент, а if на while.

Answer (score 0):

В общем, мне пришел такой вариант решения. Не знаю насколько он вообще имеет право на жизнь, но как-то так.

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
void exits(int sig) {
int b;
for(double i = 1; i <= 1000; i++){
   double f = (i / 1000);
   b = f * 100;
   printf("%d%s",b, "%" );
   sleep(1);
   printf("\n");
} 
printf("For exit press Ctrl+K \n");
sleep(3);
 (void)signal(SIGINT, SIG_DFL);

}


int main() {
(void)signal(SIGINT, exits);
 while(SIGINT){ 
printf("Press Ctrl+C to start and see the progress status.\n");
  sleep(1);}
}
```

Comment: Почитайте про signal safe functions. `printf()` еяпп таковой не является, поэтому её нельзя вызывать в обработчике.

Comment: @0andriy да тут недойдя до printf жести вагон)